# java.lang.NullPointerException in Android Webservice

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, webservice-client

me again.

I am having a little issue with my android app.

When I run the service on the phone, it starts just fine and when the call is disconnected it throws an java.lang.NullPointerException when i start the tareaEnviarABD.execute(); task.

This is the code of my service:

```
package com.trucka.llamadasdrivers;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServicioLlamadas extends Service {

    TextView txtInformacion = null;
    TextView txtDetalles = null;
    TextView tv = null;
    // Comunicación con el webservice.
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://truckanet.com/MensajeOperador";
    // private final String URL =
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.10.94/MensajeOperador/MensajeOperador.asmx";
    //private final String URL = "http://200.76.187.148/MensajeOperador/MensajeOperador.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://truckanet.com/MensajeOperador/ActualizarFede";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "ActualizarFede";
    private String TAG = "TRUCKA_DRIVERS";
    private String resultado;
    String phNumber = null;
    String callType = null;
    String callDate = null;
    DateFormat shortFecha = null;
    DateFormat shortDF = null;
    Date callDayTime = null;
    Date fin = null;
    String fechaLlamada1 = null;
    String fechaLlamada2 = null;
    String callDuration = null;
    String dir = null;
    public String tolo = null;
    String imei = null;
    String comentario = null;
    String fechaRegistro = null;
    String insercion = null;
    String fechaInicio = null;
    String fechaFin = null;
    String estadoLlamada = null;

    private static ServicioLlamadas instance = null;

    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return instance != null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA creado",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA destruído",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        instance = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA iniciado",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (estadoLlamada == "OFFHOOK") {
                    insercion = null;
                    getCallDetails();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Información enviada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                estadoLlamada = "IDLE";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                estadoLlamada = "OFFHOOK";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enviando información...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

//Obtener la fecha actual del teléfono.
    public long getTodayTimestamp() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(new Date());

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return c2.getTimeInMillis();
    }

private void getCallDetails() {
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ?", new String[] { timestamp }, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Bitácora de llamadas :");
     //managedCursor.moveToFirst();
    managedCursor.moveToLast();
    phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
    callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
    callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
    shortFecha = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    shortDF = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    fechaLlamada1 = shortDF.format(callDayTime);
    fechaLlamada2 = shortFecha.format(callDayTime);
    callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    switch (dircode) {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        dir = "Saliente";
        break;

    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        dir = "Entrante";
        break;

    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        dir = "Perdida";
        break;
    }

    imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
    comentario = dir;
    fechaRegistro = fechaLlamada2;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String ahorita = df.format(callDayTime);
    fechaInicio = ahorita.toString();

    insercion = "DECLARE @claveDriver INT, @nombreDriver VARCHAR(max), @evento VARCHAR(max), @duracion int, @inicial varchar(max) "
            + "SET @claveDriver = (SELECT cve_tra FROM SISTEMA.dbo.TELEFONOS WHERE IMEI_SIM = '"
            + mngr.getDeviceId()
            + "') "
            + "SET @nombreDriver = (SELECT nombre FROM SISTEMA.dbo.TELEFONOS WHERE IMEI_SIM = '"
            + mngr.getDeviceId()
            + "') "
            + "SET @duracion = "
            + managedCursor.getString(duration)
            + "SET @evento = '(LOG) Llamada "
            + dir
            + ". Duración ' + CONVERT(varchar, @duracion, 103) + ' segundos al número: "
            + managedCursor.getString(number)
            + "' "
            + " SET @inicial = '"
            + fechaInicio
            + "'"
            + "INSERT INTO bitacora.dbo.registroDellamadasOperadores (fechacreacion,fecha_fin,fecha_inicio,idMobil,Tractor,Nom_tra,Cve_tra,FechaRegistro,Evento) "
            + " VALUES('"
            + fechaInicio
            + "', DATEADD(SECOND,@duracion,@inicial),'"
            + fechaInicio
            + "','"
            + mngr.getDeviceId()
            + "','',@nombreDriver,@claveDriver,current_timestamp,@evento)";
    try
    {
    AsyncCallWS tareaEnviarABD = new AsyncCallWS();
    tareaEnviarABD.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        InsertarLlamada(insercion);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        txtInformacion.setText("Información enviada");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        txtInformacion.setText("Enviando información...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }
}
public void InsertarLlamada(String insercion) {
    // Creamos la solicitud
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    // Propiedades que contienen los valores
    PropertyInfo propiedades = new PropertyInfo();

    propiedades.setName("insercion");
    propiedades.setValue(insercion);
    propiedades.setType(String.class);
    // Agregamos las propiedades
    request.addProperty(propiedades);
    // Creamos el envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // ponemos la salida SOAP
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Creamos la llamada HTTP
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invocamos el servicio
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        // Obtenemos la respuesta
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
        // Asignamos el resultado de la consulta
        resultado = response.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

And the log cat shows this:

```
02-25 09:32:32.946: D/ActivityThread(8866): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
02-25 09:32:32.946: D/ActivityThread(8866): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
02-25 09:32:32.946: D/ActivityThread(8866): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
02-25 09:33:07.663: D/libEGL(8866): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-25 09:33:07.663: D/libEGL(8866): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-25 09:33:07.663: D/libEGL(8866): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-25 09:33:07.683: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(8866): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-25 09:33:07.693: E/(8866): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
02-25 09:33:07.693: E/(8866): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
02-25 09:33:07.693: D/OpenGLRenderer(8866): Enabling debug mode 0
02-25 09:33:13.128: I/TRUCKA_DRIVERS(8866): onPreExecute
02-25 09:33:13.128: D/AndroidRuntime(8866): Shutting down VM
02-25 09:33:13.128: W/dalvikvm(8866): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e48438)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ServicioLlamadas$AsyncCallWS.onPreExecute(ServicioLlamadas.java:239)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ServicioLlamadas.getCallDetails(ServicioLlamadas.java:215)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ServicioLlamadas.access$0(ServicioLlamadas.java:143)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ServicioLlamadas$TeleListener.onCallStateChanged(ServicioLlamadas.java:108)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:421)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5062)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-25 09:33:13.128: E/AndroidRuntime(8866):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 09:33:14.240: I/Process(8866): Sending signal. PID: 8866 SIG: 9
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? :(

Thanks!

Comment: Initialize:  TextView txtInformacion = null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing txtInformacion  anywhere in your code. You need to initialize it with the appropriate TextView before you can use it in onPreExecute() method of AsyncCallWS

Comment: Solved! removed the txtInformacion on the lines thanks! :) a lot!!
Love your name lol

Comment: You are welcome dude...Kakarot is an alias...I love that name too :P

Answer (score 1):

You have never initialized txtInformacion.

```
TextView txtInformacion = null;
```

So you get NPE at:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    txtInformacion.setText("Enviando información...");
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend :)

Thanks a lot for your answer, I really appreaciate it. But I do have the TextView txtInformacion = null; initialized. It is right under the public class ServicioLlamadas extends Service { line